# Should I use "having" or "have"?

Tags: gerunds, participle-clauses

I can't figure out whether this is a proper sentence

- I am an Engineer having knowledge in ..
  Or Is it proper to make it two sentence like
- I am an Engineer. I have knowledge in...

Comment: It would probably be best to not use that verb and use the preposition *with* instead: I am an engineer *with knowledge...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say " I'm an engineer and I have knowledge in ... "
Because we use "have" to mean 'to own' or diseases. And "having" for something continuous.

Of course, as Sander said, using "with" would be best.